# Unable to transfer GCS bucket from one account to another

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a transfer job in Data Transfer, to copy all files in a bucket belonging to one account to an existing bucket belonging to another account.

I get access to both source and destination buckets, I get "green light" in the wizard, but when I try to run the transfer job I get the following error message:

> To complete this transfer, you need the 'storage.buckets.setIamPolicy'
>   permission for the source bucket. Ask the bucket's administrator to
>   grant you the required permission and try again.

I have tried to apply various roles to the user runnning the transfer job, but I can't figure out how to overcome this problem.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This permission `storage.buckets.setIamPolicy` can be granted with either `roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner` or `roles/iam.securityAdmin` role. It could be needed to keep the permissions applied to the source object.

Permissions for copying an object:

- storage.objects.create (for the destination bucket)
- storage.objects.delete (for the destination bucket)
- storage.objects.get (for the source object)
- storage.objects.getIamPolicy (for the source object)
- storage.objects.setIamPolicy (for the destination bucket)

Please see:

[Cloud IAM > Documentation > Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

[Cloud Storage > Documentation > Reference > Cloud IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like the trick was to apply the same permissions to the source bucket as well.